# Find the murderer from a strange clue

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

A dead woman is found with a scrap of paper with a strange clue that reads:

> decay unlucky: terrae, no oven, MBE.

After deciphering the clue, you can narrow the suspects down to two individuals, who have the same weapon and profession.

What about their choice of clothes reveals which of the two is the murderer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to look at...

> ...the **colour** of the two suspects' clothing. Specifically, which one of them is wearing **green**.

Because the note can be understood by realising that:

> 'decay unlucky' suggests using the '**rot-13**' Caesar shift. Shifting each letter of the message by 13 characters in the alphabet, 'terrae, no oven, MBE' becomes '**greenr, ab bira, ZOR**', or with respacing:
>
>  **green/rabbi/razor**.
>
>  Presuming then that you have narrowed down the suspects to two rabbis with razors, the only part of this message that remains to be accounted for is the word '**green**', which - if we are considering their clothing - is likely to be the colour of the outfit worn by the guilty party...